# installing django sentry - no command sentry

Tags: django, sentry

I'm trying to install [sentry](http://sentry.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart/index.html). I can't run `easy_install` on my server and so I ran it with pip.

```
python-pip install --user sentry
```

The installation was successful.

The problem is that I don't have the command `sentry` after this. Any suggestions?

Comment: You have to make sure you add python to your PATH; on my system it's `/usr/local/share/python`.

Comment: I have python on my path. python command works. sentry goes to /../site-packages but I don't know what to run

Comment: Do you have python's **share** also on your PATH, similar to what I posted?

Comment: python is not in that address. How can I find it ?